# How to shuffle this in php

Tags: php

I want to shuffle output of my title. i want to some time $title value print first and $tagnem1 in end in output, but im unable to get this. here is my code please look and help me if this is possible to shuffle my $myalt.

```
$myalt = ("$catn,$tagnem, $tagnem1,$tagnem2,$title");
$arr = (array)$myalt ;
shuffle($arr);

echo '<blockquote>title="'.$myalt.' "</blockquote>';
```

> For Ex: $catn = Photo1 , $tagnem = Photo2, $tagnem1 =Photo3,
>   $tagnem2=Photo4, $title=Photo5
>
> So my code output is
>
> > title = Photo1 Photo2 photo3 Photo4 Photo5
>
> i want to out put like this
>
> > title= Photo 2 Photo 5 Photo 1 Photo 4 Photo 3

Sorry for bad English, hope you understand my question.

Comment: you shuffle $arr, but then echo the original array `$myalt` (which will not work anyway - array to string conversion).

Comment: _AAAND_ you actually don't create an array, only a string.

Comment: im new to php just search and try to make a code, i got error that why i ask

Comment: @jeff if i use $arr its print only "array" word nothing other output

Comment: `$myalt = "$catn,$tagnem, $tagnem1,$tagnem2,$title"; $arr=explode(',' , $myalt);`

Comment: @Michel thanks for try to help , i got error here you can see https://3v4l.org/EBTso

Comment: It means means that none of the variables in `"$catn,$tagnem, $tagnem1,$tagnem2,$title"` has a value. So the problem lies before this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
$myalt = ['first' => 'firsttitle', 'second'=> 'second title', 'third' => 'third 
title'];
shuffle($myalt);

foreach ($myalt as $title){ 
echo '<blockquote>title="'.$title.' "</blockquote>';
}
```

Mind you, you have to make sure your array is actually an array.

EDIT: this is what you want:

```
$myalt = ['first' => 'firsttitle', 'second'=> 'second title', 'third' => 'third 
title'];
shuffle($myalt);

$joined = join(' ', $myalt);

echo '<img src="yy"  title="'.$joined.' " >';
```

Comment: Thanks for help, its show just one value not all . like photo 1 after refresh photo 2. but not all together

Comment: i dont downvote any of answer on this page ,can you please tell  how i can use $catn value here $myalt = ['first' => 'firsttitle',  can i use like $myalt = ['first' => '$title1',

Comment: i mean like this or i do anything wrong : $myalt = ['first' => '$catn', 'second'=> '$tagnem', 'third' => '$tagnem1', 'fourth' => '$tagnem2', 'fifth' => '$title'];
shuffle($myalt);

Comment: you can just set all your variables and then have your original array `$array = array($catn, $tagnem, $tagnem1, etc...)

Comment: Thanks again, now i got this problem, can we do something for this : https://3v4l.org/rRC9b its use in < img  tag so want to print all value together one time not in loop , look this link for understanding

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean, but if you want to print a single element from an array, you can use `$array['first'] ` in an associative array or `$array[0]` for an unassociated array.

Comment: i got the way to print single <img tag but i want to print full value for title= tag . like <img src="yy" title="Photo1 Photo 5 Photo 3 photo 4 Photo 2"  our code show now only <img src="yy" title="photo 5"

Comment: please chk my last comment, you can see my question now i edit .

Comment: Now i understand. You then have to join your array, for example with a comma. Example: https://3v4l.org/0DM5k

Answer (score 0):

here's a corrected version:

```
<?php
$catn = "Photo1"; 
$tagnem = "Photo2"; 
$tagnem1 = "Photo3"; 
$tagnem2 = "Photo4"; 
$title = "Photo5";

// create a real array:
$myalt = [$catn, $tagnem, $tagnem1, $tagnem2, $title];
$arr = (array)$myalt;
shuffle($arr);
                         // use the 1st element of the shuffled array.
echo '<blockquote>title="'.$arr[0].'"</blockquote>';
```

fiddle can be found [here](https://3v4l.org/NKTrb)

Comment: No need of $arr = (array) $myalt; it's already an array. If you want only one shuffle/random record from array you can use array_rand()

Comment: @jeff thanks for help its show just one value not all . like photo 1 after refresh photo 2. but not all together